# Nested aar dependencies not working

Tags: android, maven, aar, gradle-dependencies

To simplify things I'm going to call the libraries I'm using library_a.aar and library_b.aar.

Here is the scenario that I'm facing.
library_a is build and pushed to maven_repository and no problems here.
library_b depends on library_a and added to library_b as follows:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username USERNAME
            password PASSWORD
        }
        url "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/COMPANY/maven_repository/raw/releases"
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'package:library_a:1.0'
    ...
}
```

library_b is built with no errors and uploaded to the maven_repository.

Now my application depends on library_b which I need to add by providing (as above) the repository along with the credentials.

The first issue that I'm facing is that in order to compile library_b in my project it needs to be compiled in the following way:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'package:library_b:1.0@aar'
    ...
}
```

I have to add the @aar otherwise gradle won't recognize it, but I didn't have to do that with library_a.

The second issue is that when I build the app I get warnings that it can't find references to classes available in library_a. What am I missing over here? I did try to add transitive=true to library_a

```
dependencies {
        ...
        compile ('package:library_a:1.0') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        ...
}
```

but absolutely nothing works. I did check the pom file and it includes the proper dependencies.
Could it be that what I'm doing is not supported by gradle and I have to compile both library_a and library_b in my app?

Comment: How do you upload the aar's to the maven repo? By executing a gradle task or by hand?

Comment: @larsgrefer I used https://github.com/JeroenMols/GitAsMaven to upload

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your maven repo only contains the `aar` files but no or wrong `pom` files.

Are you using the following gradle plugin and the `uploadArchives` gradle task in order to upload the `aar`s to your maven repository?
https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin

try this gradle snippet for your `aar`s:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

android { ... }

dependencies { ... }

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/COMPANY/maven_repository/raw/releases") {
                authentication(userName: USERNAME, password: PASSWORD)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the `uploadArchives` gradle task

Comment: the pom file is there with the right dependencies. I have used GitAsMaven github example (https://github.com/JeroenMols/GitAsMaven).